# Is it possible to install `paprefs` in CentOS 8?

Tags: centos, pulseaudio

I wish to install `paprefs` (pulseaudio preferences) in CentOS 8, however I've run into what looks like a dead end.

At first, I received this error:

```
Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
 - nothing provides libglademm-2.4.so.1()(64bit) needed by paprefs-0.9.10-8.el6.nux.x86_64
 - nothing provides libgconfmm-2.6.so.1()(64bit) needed by paprefs-0.9.10-8.el6.nux.x86_64
 - nothing provides pulseaudio-module-gconf needed by paprefs-0.9.10-8.el6.nux.x86_64
```

The issue here is `libglademm24` doesn't appear to be available for CentOS 8 according to pkgs.org: https://pkgs.org/download/libglademm24

I tried installing `libglade2` from one of these (I don't remember which provided it):

```
dnf install -y http://li.nux.ro/download/nux/dextop/el8/x86_64/nux-dextop-release-0-2.el8.nux.noarch.rpm
dnf install -y https://mirrors.rpmfusion.org/free/el/rpmfusion-free-release-8.noarch.rpm
```

However this didn't satisfy the dependency.

Comment: Where are you trying to install the package from? The `el6` dist tag in the name suggests it was build for CentOS 6. You might have a wrong repo set up for your machine.

Comment: Yes I noticed that just now, but there isn't an `el8` for nux-desktop, only `el6` and `el7`

Answer (score 1):

CentOS 8 is based on Fedora 28 ([source](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/fedora-and-red-hat-enterprise-linux/index.html)).  Therefore you may be able to load its `paprefs` RPM package, e.g. from the archives here:

https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/28/Everything/x86_64/os/Packages/p/

You can get Fedora's PGP keys to check package signatures [from here](https://getfedora.org/security/).  fc28 packages should be signed by key id 128C F232 A937 1991 C8A6 5695 E08E 7E62 **9DB6 2FB1** if I read that page's source correctly.